# Odoo v12 - Uncaught TypeError: odoo.define is not a function

Tags: developer-console, odoo-12, odoo-enterprise

I am using Odoo v12 and when I try to access one of my database through browser it doesn't loads up properly. It comes up as blank screen and when I checked the developer console it shows following error:

Uncaught TypeError: odoo.define is not a function

[Odoo -12: Developer console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvA5q.jpg)

Comment: Restart odoo and check server logs

Answer (score 15):

It's a little late for this answer but still will give it a try. This seems to be an Odoo unsolved issue (happened to me with Odoo 12). There are a few workarounds:

quick fix: `DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE url LIKE '/web/content/%';`

If it doesn't work, try cleaning browser cache and retry.

If it doesn't work, just delete the db and postgresql's user and recreate them.

Recreating the DB usually works.

I know all of these are workarounds, but so far, this issue hasn't been solved by the Odoo team.

You can [track the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/13808)

Comment: Worked, saved my morning. Thanks.

Comment: The query worked but I had to restart Odoo.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the browser --> Network --> refresh by checking and unchecking the disable cache option.

Only a temprory solution